# What is the difference between these 2 structures

Tags: c#, layout, structure, pinvoke

There are 2 ways I can define this structure which I wish to pass as an argument to a pinvoke function. I wanted to know what was the difference between the 2

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect {
   public int left;
   public int top;
   public int right;
   public int bottom;
}   

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Rect {
   [FieldOffset(0)] public int left;
   [FieldOffset(4)] public int top;
   [FieldOffset(8)] public int right;
   [FieldOffset(12)] public int bottom;
}
```

From the definitions of layouts I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t2cwe11.aspx), shouldnt both look the same in memory? Any advantages of one over the other?

Comment: The first one is sane, and the second one is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From the definitions of layouts I found here, shouldn't both look the same in memory?

Yes, they will look the same in memory.

> Any advantages of one over the other?

One's faster to type out, and is easier to read.

---

The use of `FieldOffset` is of course a useful tool; it's not like it's *always* useless, but if you just so happen to use it to explicitly lay out the fields in the manor in which they would be laid out by default, then it's useless.  If you use it to lay out fields in a manor other than their default value (for example, having the overlap, adding padding space, having the underlying representation be in a different order than the declaration order, etc.), then it's not useless.

Comment: I agree if you're not doing anything fancy like reordering, spacing values with padding, etc.  Then the first version is simpler, will be more maintainable, and will lead to less mistakes.  What happens when you want to add a field (now you have to do math and might mess up).

Answer (score 1):

In theory these two are exactly the same. Typically you would use the explicit layout when you are interacting with non-managed code. <s>This can be important because in the future "int" might not have 32 bits in it - meaning that the sequential layout might no longer be applicable.</s> Hopefully this helps a bit!

**Edit**

One more thought is if you were mapping a .NET structure to an unmanaged union or using different types in .NET than in unmanaged code this would be really useful.

**Second Edit**

Others have noted that MS will "never" change the size of an int. I can agree this would be a breaking change and it is therefore *highly* unlikely. That said, being explicit about structure mapping when marshaling values between .NET and unmanaged code can still be a good idea. This is especially true if there is a possibility of unmanaged structure/layout changing in the future.

Comment: `in the future "int" might not have 32 bits in it`  That's most certainly not true.  In C# `int` is just an alias for `System.Int32`.  It will always be 32 bits, as opposed to, say, C++ in which only a minimum size is defined.

Comment: @Servy I would like to think you are correct, but its possible that Microsoft could change the compiler at some point (not without warning of course). At that point, all of these values would need to be remapped using the explicit layout.

Comment: @drew_w: No; Microsoft will _never_ change the size of `int`.  That would be one of the biggest breaking changes imaginable.

Comment: They've made it very clear that the size of an int is *always* 32 bits.  It is very explicit about it; it's not just some implementation detail.  I'm quite confident that they wouldn't make a breaking change like that.

Comment: Lets just say I'm hesitant to say "never" in the world of programming. Certainly pointer sizes have changed over time and if at some point we have 256 bit processors (someday?) I would see a time when Microsoft *could* provide a primitive other than "long" that would allow a programmer to access these benefits. Likely? Maybe not - but who am I to judge!

Comment: @drew_w Sure pointer sizes change.  There's already a 32 and 64 bit runtime.  The point is that `int` is not the size of one word.  The language specs *specifically* state that it is 32 bits.  They could create a new type that is an integer type that is the size of one word, but they wouldn't change `int` to do it.  `long` is also fixed.  It is *always* 64 bits, not the size of one word, or the size of two words, etc.  It's just 64 bits.  That's what the specs say it is.  To do otherwise would be to violate the language's own definition.

Comment: @Servy I think this is probably a philosophical discussion since no one can actually predict the future. I agree that *in principle* they wouldn't change this but siting the current documentation as a reason is not good enough. Documentation is versioned with the language. As new releases of .NET come out the size of an integer could be changed and the documentation would simply be updated. Again - I agree this wouldn't be a wise change or one I would predict but it is - strictly speaking - possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a real better layout version for this problem. The second version with the `Explicit` `LayoutKind` though allows you to change the order of the structure's members as you indicate their position in the memory with the fieldoffest.
The second version is easier to expand in my opinion.